# How to use multiply rows with ResponsiveDatatable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a second row after the icon "Bearbeiten", but this is not possible, because I need to use "title" for the first row. `child: ResponsiveDatatable(title: Row(`

I want to have a code like this below. How can I use ResponsiveDatatable, but although use a second row for my buttons?
[This image shows, how the code looks at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXx4L.png) 
(without the second row). Because there is not enough space in one row, I want to create a second row.

How can I do this with a ResponsiveDatatable?

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: 700,
                  ),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 1,
                    shadowColor: Colors.black,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                    child: ResponsiveDatatable(
                      title: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[

                          //add user to the list
                          TextButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => {
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RegristrationRoute)
                          
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            label: Text("Hinzufügen",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,

                                )
                            ),
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),
                              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                  EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                            ),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(width: 30,),

                          TextButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => {
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RegristrationRoute)
                              //Pop-up Fenster für die Registration machen, wenn Zeit - ansonsten registrationsfenster weiterleiten
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              IconData(0xf00d, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                              color: Colors.black,

                            ),
                            label: Text("Bearbeiten",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,

                                )
                            ),
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),
                              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                  EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                            ),
                          ),]),

                          child: Row(      //error, I am not allowed to use child because of title
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[


                          SizedBox(width: 30,),

                          TextButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => {},
                            icon: Icon(
                              IconData(0xe3b1, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                              color: Colors.black,

                            ),
                            label: Text("Sperren",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,


                                )
                            ),
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),
                              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                  EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                            ),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(width: 30,),

                          TextButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () => {},
                            icon: Icon(
                              IconData(0xe3b0, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                              color: Colors.black,

                            ),
                            label: Text("Freischalten",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,

                                )
                            ),
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),
                              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                  EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                            ),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(width: 30,),

                          TextButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () async => {
                              await AuthProvider.deleteUser(uid),
                              print(uid + 'user gelöscht')
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              IconData(0xe1bb, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                              color: Colors.black,

                            ),
                            label: Text("Löschen",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,

                                )
                            ),
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),
                              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                  EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

Comment: can you give the ui image which you are expecting?

Comment: a second row which divide the buttons. So I don't have 4 buttons in a row - just 2. Because of this I would have more space. At the moment when I shrink the screensize till tablet or mobile size, then the buttons need to much space, which results in a pixel error. With multiply rows it would look nicer and the buttons would have enough space, which solve the pixel error.

Comment: try to use Wrap instead of Row for the buttons. It will simply solve the responsive issue. Or you can remove the buttons from the table and have it separate Wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are expecting is the functionality of the Column.

```
ResponsiveDatatable(
                      title: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                TextButton.icon(
                                  onPressed: () => {
                                    Navigator.of(context)
                                        .pushNamed(RegristrationRoute)
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.add,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  label: Text("Hinzufügen",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )),
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                            Colors.grey),
                                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                        EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 30,),
                                TextButton.icon(
                                  onPressed: () => {
                                    Navigator.of(context)
                                        .pushNamed(RegristrationRoute)
                                    //Pop-up Fenster für die Registration machen, wenn Zeit - ansonsten registrationsfenster weiterleiten
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    IconData(0xf00d, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  label: Text("Bearbeiten",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )),
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                            Colors.grey),
                                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                        EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                TextButton.icon(
                                  onPressed: () => {},
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    IconData(0xe3b1, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  label: Text("Sperren",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )),
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                            Colors.grey),
                                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                        EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 30,),
                                TextButton.icon(
                                  onPressed: () => {},
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    IconData(0xe3b0, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  label: Text("Freischalten",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )),
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                            Colors.grey),
                                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                        EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 30,),
                                TextButton.icon(
                                  onPressed: () async => {
                                    // await AuthProvider.deleteUser(uid),
                                    // print(uid + 'user gelöscht')
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    IconData(0xe1bb, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  label: Text("Löschen",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )),
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                            Colors.grey),
                                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                        EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ]),
                      source: [],
                    )))
```

And there is a minor error in the parenthesis closing also.
Note: It will solve your problem but still it will not meet responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem.
Instead of TextButton, I made a button-UI in container and wrapped it with InkWell (A rectangular area of a Material that responds to touch).

```
        InkWell(
          // on Tap function used and call back function as defined here
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              // state will be set when the inkwell area is tapped
              inkwell='Inkwell Tapped';
            });
          },
          onLongPress: () {
            setState(() {
              inkwell='InkWell Long Pressed';
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            // container displaying the text
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 120,
              height: 70,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Button text',
                  ))),
        ),
```

Comment: I can't use a container - when I try to use child: Container instead of child: Row, then it is still an error.  "The named parameter 'child' isn't defined."